# How to add condition to my logstash grok filter?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have 3 servers:

1. Elasticsearch / Kibana
2. Logstash
3. Web server

On the web server, I have filebeat and metricbeat running. I want the apache logs being sent by filebeat to be grok'd, but not the metricbeat system logs.

On my logstash server I have a file in /etc/logstash/conf.d/ called "apache-filter.conf" here is what the file looked like when it worked:

```
filter {
    grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    }
    grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{IP:client}"}
    }
    geoip {
    source => "client"
    }
}
```

Then I added a conditional and it broke (data is passed to elasticsearch raw with no filters applied):

```
filter {
  if [filebeat] in [_index] {
    grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    }
    grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{IP:client}"}
    }
    geoip {
    source => "client"
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's an example "_index" field from the Discover tab in Kibana:

```
_index          filebeat-2018.04.06
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` operator does an exact match on a list of strings.  You need to pattern match:

```
if ([_index] =~ /filebeat/) {
  // filters here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried your solution, but it didn't work.

Comment: Update: actually it did work. It just needed parentheses around the conditional statement. Thank you so much!!!